# MATLAB parentheses upon object created inside of class calls class constructor

Tags: matlab

```matlab
classdef Dog < handle
    properties
        data;
    end

    methods
        function self = Dog(varargin)
            disp("Dog()")
        end

        function out = new(~)
            out = Dog();
            out('bark') = 1;
        end
    end
end
```

`d=Dog()`; why does `d.new()` print below?

```matlab
Dog()
Dog()
Dog()
```

It also bypasses `subsref` if I overload it. Entering `d` in console gives

```matlab
ans = 

  1×114 Dog array with properties:

    data
```

and isn't reproduced with `d('bark') = 1`.

The behavior changes if I get rid of `varargin`, instead there's an error. Also why `1x114`?

Comment: Besides the excellent point in the answer below about `subsref` not being called (it's `subsasgn` you're using), I believe that within class methods, the indexing operations are always the builtin ones. This is why you can do `self.data` in class methods, even if `subsref` is overloaded to disallow accessing the property.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks, and feel free to post another answer as I think the existing one credits me with too much knowledge.

Comment: I tried to explain things the way I understand them, I hope that's helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, within class methods, indexing expressions always use the built-in `subsasgn` and `subsref`, not the overloaded (customized) one you might write yourself. This is so that overloading these functions doesn't remove the ability of class methods to access object properties.

So, within your class method, `out(i)` accesses the `i`th object in the array `out`. This is not `out.data(i)`, `out` is really an array of objects of class `Dog`. `Dog()` creates a 1x1 array, which you would normally think of as an object, but it really is an array. Everything in MATLAB is an array!

Now for `out('bark') = 1`. `'bark'`, as explained by [user16372530's anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73550269/7328782), is a 4-element array, with numeric values `[98 97 114 107]`. Thus `out`, which starts off as a 1x1 array of your custom class, is resized to an array of 114 elements, and to 4 of those elements you assign `1`. Here, MATLAB needs to create an empty element to fill out the 113 new elements, so calls `Dog()` once and copies the result to each of those elements. Then it needs to convert `1` to your class, so calls `Dog(1)` to do so, and copies to result to the 4 indexed elements. *Actually, [as indicated by
user16372530 in a comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73549992/matlab-parentheses-upon-object-created-inside-of-class-calls-class-constructor/73562936?noredirect=1#comment129905763_73562936), first `1` is converted and then the empty object is created.*

If you want your class method to use the overloaded indexing operator, you need to explicitly call `subsasgn` or `subsref`, which is ugly and hard to read. There really is no way, as far as I understand it, to use class objects inside the class methods as you actually intend your class to be used. The same code behaves differently inside a class method and outside of it.

MATLAB OOP has some really interesting features, but it also has a lot of weird and inconvenient things. I guess they did their best designing a custom class system within the previously existing MATLAB array syntax.

Comment: Much clearer, thanks. So `Dog()` is called because `out` must be filled by `Dog`-types? And how should I interpret "even classes are arrays" - are classes overloaded arrays in MATLAB, or are they stored in arrays? Also I suspect you're right on in-class behavior as I have in fact overridden `subasgn` that should've made it work differently, also other observations.

Comment: @Cris Luengo: When I do debugging with my MATLAB version (R2019b Update 4), the constructor call with argument ```1``` is actually performed before the call without any element. So I guess, elements at indices ```[98 97 114 107]``` are set first and then elements at the remaining indices as described in my answer. In your answer, it is the other way around, which might not be correct. Maybe you can check yourself?

Comment: @user16372530 I don’t have access to MATLAB right now, but trust your findings. I was guessing at the order. Will update the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon There is nothing in MATLAB that isn’t an array. The constant `0` is a 1x1 array of doubles. `obj = Dog()` is a 1x1 array of `Dog` objects. `'bark'` is a 1x4 array of chars. Everything is an array. If you do `builtin('size', obj)` you’ll get back [1,1]. After the “bark” indexing, you’ll get back [114,1].

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon For example think of the struct. You index it as `s(i,j).field`. It’s an array, each element is what in other languages you call a struct. A custom object is the same thing, but additionally with constraints on the fields, and a class ID. Methods are just overloaded functions, so even that is not different!

Comment: But `x.bark` _"Dot indexing is not supported for variables of this type"_ if `x = [1 2]`. So the question is where class capabilities come from. My guess is one of the two I described. Since MATLAB arrays can hold classes, the arrays themselves must be classes, then "classes are arrays" is really "classes inherit the array class". I'm talking backends.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon There are arrays of doubles, arrays of chars, arrays of structs, arrays of custom classes, and arrays of arrays (aka cell array). The array has a type, all its elements are of that type. Your `x` is an array of doubles, which doesn’t have a dot indexing.

Comment: What I'm saying is "classes are arrays" is invalid if interpreted directly. Arrays store data, they can't do anything else. MATLAB is coded in C, so I can understand "classes are arrays" as "classes are wrapped in arrays" i.e. the arrays store class pointers. Its own topic at any rate.

Answer (score 6):

Here is what's happening when calling `d.new()` (after `d = Dog()`):

1. `out = Dog();` is invoked. This constructor call triggers the first output of "Dog()"
2. `out('bark') = 1;` is invoked, which triggers the following:

   - The characters of `'bark'` are interpreted as values `[98 97 114 107 ]`. Consequently, Matlab resizes `out` to a size of 114.
   - To construct a `Dog` object to fill positions `[98 97 114 107 ]` in `out`, Matlab calls the constructor again, this time with the input argument `varargin` equal to `{ 1 }`. This triggers the second output of "Dog()".
   - To construct a `Dog` object  to fill the other positions in `out`, Matlab calls the constructor again, this time with no input argument. This triggers the third output of "Dog()".

Furthermore, `subsref` is not bypassed, but simply not called, as you do not refer to the object in a reading manner.

And when you remove `varargin`, you get the error, because the constructor cannot be called anymore with one input argument, as explained in the second bullet point under 2. above.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but regrettably I don't understand any of the bullet points. Why resize, why's anything "filled" at all, why is it done with `Dog({1})`? Why are other positions filled with `Dog()`? Why does any of this require the constructor instead of just `subasgn`?